# How to validate ftp host name using regular expression

Tags: regex, validation, knockout.js, ftp

I want to validate the ftp host name using knock out js. I have defined the validation in knockout like below:

```
 selfLeadAdapter.Url = ko.observable(data.Url).extend({
                        required: { message: "Host required." }
                      }).extend({
                          pattern: {
                              message: 'Hey this doesnt match my pattern',                                  
                              params: /((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/i
                          }
                      });
```

But the regular expression is for validating the webpage or website. I want to validate the ftp host name. This will be in the form of ftp://ftp.example.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use this expression :

```
/^ftp:\/\/(.*)$/i
```

you can be more specific, it's depend what you expect exactly.
By example :

```
/^ftp:\/\/(\w*\.\w*\.com)$/i
```